# Ffmpeg fails to encode mp2.mxf "failed to find absolute offset of xxxxxx in BodySID 1 - partial file?"

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a lot of  audio file Op1 Atom From Avid Interplay.
They are Mxf with codec mpeg1 layer2. ffprobe show MP2
This is the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XB_marJHwHDbK-KJfLcPj6ryQjyIwjo0
when I try to convert it ffmpeg convert only first 16 minuts and then goes wrong with: "failed to find absolute offset of xxxxxx in BodySID 1 - partial file?" This for all file.
Only potplayer (that use ffmpeg) can play it in whole duration, 2h
I need encode the whole audio stream
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with two pass,
in the first:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -map 0:a -acodec copy -y output.mp2
```

I get the same error but the output file it's whole
and then it's possible remux in new container without error